# Firebase Android accessing child

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, parent-child, firebaseui

I request your help today beacause i have a problem with my app using FirebaseDatabase and FireBaseAdapter .

The Structure of the DB look like that:

```
`{
  "First_Main_Node" : {
    "Child_Node1" : {
      "description" : "Blabla",
      "image" : "Image1.jpg",
      "title" : "My Awesome Title"
    },
    "Child_Node2" : {
      "description" : "Blabla",
      "image" : "Image2.jpg",
      "title" : "My Awesome Title"
    },
    "Child_Node3" : {
      "description" : "Blabla",
      "image" : "Image3.jpg",
      "title" : "My Awesome Title"
    },
    "Child_Node4" : {
      "description" : "Blabla",
      "image" : "Image4.jpg",
      "title" : "My Awesome Title"
    },
    "Child_Node5" : {
      "description" : "Blabla",
      "image" : "Image5.jpg",
      "title" : "My Awesome Title"
    },
    "Child_Node6" : {
      "description" : "Blabla",
      "image" : "Image6.jpg",
      "title" : "My Awesome Title"
    },
    "Child_Node7" : {
      "description" : "Blabla",
      "image" : "Image7.jpg",
      "title" : "My Awesome Title"
    },
    "Child_Node8" : {
      "description" : "Blabla",
      "image" : "Image8.jpg",
      "title" : "My Awesome Title"
    }
  },
  "Second_Main_Node" : {
    "Child_Node1" : {
       "Element" : {
          "image" : "Image1.jpg",
          "price" : "100",
          "title" : "My Awesome Title"
    }
  }
    }`
```

My App's main activity is a RecyclerView w/ Cardviews that i populate using **FirebaseAdapter**, it populate the viewHolder by fetching the child of the **First_Main_Node** using this line of code :

```
    myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("/First_Main_Node");
```

Thing is, as you can see in the DB structure, there is a **Second_Main_Node**, whom has Nested Child_Node who has Nested Element itself who finally has title,price,image child .

My Problem comes here , i want to access **Second_Main_Node > Child_Node1** and Populate another RecyclerView but this Time with all the "Element" children within Child_Node1

I tried the line of code above , by changing child method path parameter by **/Second_Main_Node/Child_Node1** , but either the RecyclerView Shows a Cardview with "**Null**" as title and nothing else happens, or my app crashs immediately after opening the second RecyclerView , i tried to change Reference, Child, both without success, i don't understand how i can access those elements and populate the second RecyclerView , i don't think it's that hard but it been almost a week i'm trying to fix this problem .

**Here is the Code Relative to the MainActivity RecyclerView**

```
recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);


    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 2));


    myref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("/First_Main_Node");

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Watch, MainActivity.WatchViewHolder> recyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Watch, MainActivity.WatchViewHolder>(

            Watch.class,
            R.layout.individual_row,
            MainActivity.WatchViewHolder.class,
            myref
    ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(final MainActivity.WatchViewHolder viewHolder, final Watch model, int position) {

            viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, WatchDisplayActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);

                }
            });


            viewHolder.setTitle(model.getTitle());
            viewHolder.setDescription(model.getDescription());
            viewHolder.setImage(model.getImage());


        }
    };
    recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);


}

public static class WatchViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    View mView;
    TextView textView_title;
    TextView textView_description;
    ImageView imageView;


    public WatchViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mView = itemView;
        textView_title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_titre);
        textView_description = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_desc);
        imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_image);



    }



    public void setTitle(String title) {
        textView_title.setText(title + "");
    }


    public void setDescription(String description) {


        textView_description.setText(description);
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        Picasso.with(mView.getContext())
                .load(image)
                .into(imageView);
    }

}
```

}

**And The One Relative To The Second RecylerView**

```
 rv_display.setHasFixedSize(true);
    rv_display.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this,2));


    myref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("/Second_Main_Node/Child_Node1");



    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Watch, WatchDisplayActivity.WatchViewHolder> recyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Watch, WatchViewHolder>(

            Watch.class,
            R.layout.individual_row_display,
            WatchDisplayActivity.WatchViewHolder.class,
            myref
    ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(WatchViewHolder viewHolder, Watch model, int position) {

            viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Test",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            viewHolder.setTextView_price(model.getPrice());
            viewHolder.setImageView(model.getImage());
            viewHolder.setTextView_title(model.getTitle());
        }
    };rv_display.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);


}


public static class WatchViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    View mView;
    TextView textView_title;
    TextView textView_price;
    ImageView imageView;


    public WatchViewHolder(View itemView){
        super(itemView);
        mView = itemView;
        textView_price = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_price_display);
        textView_title = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_titre_display);
        imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_image_display);

    }




    public void setTextView_title(String title) {
        textView_title.setText(title + "");
    }

    public void setTextView_price(String price) {
        textView_price.setText(price);
    }

    public void setImageView(String image) {
        Picasso.with(mView.getContext())
                .load(image)
                .into(imageView);
    }
}
```

**And This is the Logcat**

```
02-26 16:57:41.103 19143-19143/package_name E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                 Process: fr.package_name, PID: 19143
                                                                 com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert value of type java.lang.Double to String
                                                                     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zg.zzb(Unknown Source)
                                                                     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zg.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zg.zzb(Unknown Source)
                                                                     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zh.zze(Unknown Source)
                                                                     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zg.zzb(Unknown Source)
                                                                     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zg.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                     at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source)
                                                                     at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.parseSnapshot(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:154)
                                                                     at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.getItem(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:143)
                                                                     at com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.onBindViewHolder(FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java:183)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6482)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6515)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5458)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5724)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5563)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5559)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2229)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager.layoutChunk(GridLayoutManager.java:556)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1516)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:608)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(GridLayoutManager.java:170)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3693)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3410)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.consumePendingUpdateOperations(RecyclerView.java:1710)
                                                                     at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$1.run(RecyclerView.java:346)
                                                                     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
                                                                     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
                                                                     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:603)
                                                                     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:234)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5526)
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                     at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:102)
```

Comment: You've included a picture of your code and of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual code and JSON as text. The latter you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the code and JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: Also: the line you shared doesn't do anything with a recycler view. Please make sure you share the [minimal, **complete** code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (read the link, it is quite useful).

Comment: Ok just give me a moment i do this right now

Comment: i edited the text

Comment: The path `/Second_Main_Node/Child_Node1` for the second adapter seems fine. Did you start it listening? Also: is the first adapter really relevant here, given that the path that the second adapter listens on is fixed?

Comment: I tried this path but still, either it give me a cardview with null value as title or it crash when I click on the first RecyclerView of the first activitiy, what do you mean by "start it listening "? 
The first adapter is linked to the first RecyclerView of the first activity,  the second adapter to the second RV and second Activity. I set an Onclicklistener on items of the first recyclerView in order to try an intent to change and switch to the second activity,  this works perfectly,  but the problem occurs when I'm in the second activity dealing with the second RecyclerView

Comment: Never mind the starting of a listener. I see that you're using an older version of FirebaseUI which doesn't require that yet. Two things you can do to make it easier to help you: 1) reproduce the problem with less code. If only one listener is needed to reproduce the problem, it's easier to find what's going on. 2) you say that the app crashes. If it does so, there must be a stack trace in the logcat. Find it and add it to your question.

Comment: There's something strange, because when I set child as. Child(/First_Main_Node) on the second RecyclerView,  I have the exact same RecyclerView than the first activitiy,  meaning that the code is good,  so it either comes from Firebase or,  my code when I try to set a new path,  I don't know

Comment: Please add the error from your logcat.

Comment: I edited and added the Logcat to my question, this is the Exception that comes after wrapping ̀`myref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("/Second_Main_Node/Child_Node1");` code on a try/catch Block

Comment: I think I've found the solution,  I have to change price type from string to long,  I'll try this when I'm back home

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved,  indeed price child expected a String and I was giving a long/float type. 
By adding double quotes on price value like this `price: "99,9"` instead of `price: 99,9`

It solved the problem and I can now access child nodes without crash or exception